# javascript css rotate stop stops working in IE and FF

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, firefox, rotation

After I change icon, rotate no longer works in Internet Explorer and Firefox, but it does in other browsers.

Here is the [page](http://flamencopeko.net/icons_rotate_not_mie_and_ff.php)

Here is the [source](http://flamencopeko.net/icons_rotate_not_mie_and_ff.txt)

js:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
var position = "up";
function rotate()
{
if (position == "right"){
current_image.className = 'rotate_down BigPicture';
position = "down";
}
else if(position == "down"){
current_image.className = 'rotate_left BigPicture';
position = "left";
}
else if(position == "left"){
current_image.className = 'rotate_up BigPicture';
position = "up";
}
else if(position == "up"){
current_image.className = 'rotate_right BigPicture';
position = "right";
}
}
//-->
</script>
```

css:

```
<style>
.rotate_left
{
transform: rotate(270deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
-o-transform: rotate(270deg);
}
.rotate_right
{
transform: rotate(90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.rotate_up
{
transform: rotate(0deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
-o-transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.rotate_down
{
transform: rotate(180deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
-o-transform: rotate(180deg);
}
</style>
```

This code works but crashed with some other code in the document (in said browsers).

Comment: I also tried to put the css above the js. Didn't help.

Comment: Which IE? Transforms don't work in IE<9. In any case, one IE is significantly different from another and none of them work like any other.

Comment: I'm on XP (yepp), so I'm stuck with IE 8. Transforms do indeed not work there, as you say. And I don't care. What I'm asking for help with here is figuring out why the rotate js functions stop working after the icon has been changed in IE and FF.

Comment: Today's Firefox 23 release didn't solve the problem either.

Comment: IE doesn't need the prefix for `transform`, so you should drop the `-ms-transform` styles entirely. Also, you should *always* put the unprefixed version of a style at the end of the list, *after* the prefixed versions. (try it; this might even fix the problem, if the issue is due to FF dropping support for the prefix)

Comment: Wow. Thanks. Never heard about this. Turns out it was working in latest MIE all the time. So I'm keeping the -ms-transform: rotate(180deg); to support older versions of MIE. It does not bother latest MIE. Moving unprefixed version of a style to the end of the list didn't make any difference, as far as I can see.

Comment: I've upgraded to Win 7, IE 10 and FF 23.0.1. No one have any idea on this issue?

Comment: In IE it's slow. I must wait like a second between rotates.

Comment: Got it from 707 Errors, 10 warnings to 13 Errors, 11 warnings 

with this new try: http://flamencopeko.net/icons_rotate_not_mie_and_ff_3.php, 

according to http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fflamencopeko.net%2Ficons_rotate_not_mie_and_ff_3.php&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices. 

Didn't help.

Comment: Stripped version: http://flamencopeko.net/icons_rotate_not_mie_and_ff_stripped.php.

Still no luck.